# content_tag() in loop through messages generates nested lists

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-lists, erb

I'm trying to create a view that will display error messages conditionally, based on invalid input into a form. I have the error messages portion of the view in a partial called _error_messages.html.erb. Here's the code for that file:

```
<% if @new_partner.errors.any? %>
    <p>The form contains <%= pluralize(@new_partner.errors.count, "error") %></p>
    <ul>
        <% @new_partner.errors.each do |message| %>
            <%= content_tag(:li, message) %>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

When there are errors on the form, the partial generates multiple un-ordered lists with an empty list item. Here's the generated HTML:

```
The form contains 3 errors
        <ul>
            <li></li>
        <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
        <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
        <li>
```

The thing is I've tested the form with different errors, and the count is always right. Also the number of lists the code produces is consistent with that number. What am I not seeing?

Comment: If you use "<li><%= message %></li>" instead of "<%= content_tag(:li, message) %>", what will happen?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be looping through `errors.messages` as `@new_partner.errors` gives you an instance of [`ActiveModel::Errors`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html).

Then `errors.messages` is going to hold an [`ActiveSupport::OrderedHash`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/OrderedHash.html) of model attributes with error as key and error message as value.

Updated code using `map` to loop over `@new_partner.errors.messages` hash.

```
<% @new_partner.errors.messages.map do |attr, message| %>
  <%= content_tag(:li, "#{attr} #{message}") %>
<% end %>
```

`ActiveModel::Errors` also gives you a `full_messages` method which returns an array of full error messages.  In which case if you choose to do so, you can update the above code as:

```
<% @new_partner.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
  <%= content_tag(:li, message) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you. The original problem I ended up having was due to the fact that I was rendering the partial from 'shared/' but I had somehow made a copy of it, stuck it in 'layout/' and started working with that. So my original code (which was full of dumb mistakes because I typed it up quickly without paying much attention) actually was what was still being used, and it was totally different than what I posted here, which is why the loop would make multiple `<ul>` tags. I fixed it and had it working perfectly about 2 minutes after I posted here but I couldn't find this post to mark it as solved.

Comment: @Hugo, that's great you solved the issue.  You could add an answer yourself and mark that as answer.  That will definitely clear up any confusion for any future readers.

Answer (score 0):

So the lesson to learn from this question is to keep track of your files.

The `_error_messages.html.erb` partial was originally being rendered from `app/views/shared/`. I had accidentally created a copy of the file and stuck it in `app/views/layouts/` where the rest of the partials go, and continued to work on that file. As a result, none of what I was changing was being rendered on the final web page. By overwriting the partial in `shared/` with the one in `layouts/` it used the working code that I had written when I was paying more attention.

Bugs often times come out of these stupid situations, so make sure you double check all the basic things before asking for help, because things like this happen more often than you would think.